# PHP Cookie not working

Tags: php, cookies

I have the following code:

```
    if ($_COOKIE['lightbox'] != "1") {
        setcookie("lightbox", "1", time()+3600);
        echo("
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        if (window.addEventListener) { // Mozilla, Netscape, Firefox
            window.addEventListener('load', WindowLoad2, false);
        } else if (window.attachEvent) { // IE
            window.attachEvent('onload', WindowLoad2);
        }

        function WindowLoad2(event) {
            displayLightbox();
        }
        </script>
       ");

    }
```

What I'm basically trying to accomplish it to run displayLightbox() only once for each user by using a cookie. For some reason, I'm getting it for each page I'm going to on the website, except for when I CTRL+F5 the page. After using ctrl+f5 I no longer get the lightbox. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that this code runs in an frame/iframe? Or maybe you get this code using ajax? Because it seems that this code is cached.

Comment: @Karolis I'm implementing this in a system that does some code optimization automatically, not sure how and what exactly as that part of the code is unavailable for me. Is there any way of disabling the caching for that part of the code or bypassing it in some way?

Comment: It's difficult to say something without knowledge about your system. But you can try to add no-caching headers: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#example-3696 or alternatively you can test for cookie existence in JavaScript.

Comment: @Karolis - How can I test cookie existence with JS?

Comment: There are some examples: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 1):

It seems the first time when your cookie isn't set, the event is added to your window (unless you do a CTRL+F5) and hence on every page-load, it invokes `displayLightbox()`.Try cancelling the event in the ELSE part of your IF.

Alternatively, try changing your JS code to this:

```
if ($_COOKIE['lightbox'] != "1") {
    setcookie("lightbox", "1", time()+3600);
    echo("
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        displayLightbox();
        </script>
    ");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Or W: Do you mean you get the same result after you cancelled the event in your code OR after you tried with my code? Can you manually check, using browser settings or using FF Web Developer plugin, if the cookie is being set? Or perhaps can you do a `print_r($_COOKIE)`?